# Primes satisfy $pq+1=rt?$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Are there infinitely many primes $p, q, r, t$ satisfies $pq+1=rt$?

$$2\cdot7+1=3\cdot5$$
$$2\cdot19+1=3\cdot13$$
$$2\cdot43+1=3\cdot29$$
$$3\cdot31+1=2\cdot47$$

Obviusly one of the primes must be $2$. I guess this is an open problem. Is there any work on this?

Comment: The best result that I am aware of is that there are infinitely many semiprime pairs $pq> rt$ such that $pq-rt\leq 26$.  [See this 2005 paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0506067v1.pdf).  It continues to say that if an appropriate generalization of the [Elliott-Halberstam Conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliott%E2%80%93Halberstam_conjecture) is true, then the above bound can be improved to 6.

Comment: **Are there infinitely many pairs of consecutive semiprimes ?** - This is what you're asking, right ?